# How to consistently play Demon's Souls with a friend?

Tags: demons-souls

I want to consistently play (co-op) Demon's Souls with a friend online. Assuming we are both new to the game:

1. What is the earliest we can start playing together? Can we start playing together immediately after creating a character?
2. How can we play together?
3. How can we ensure we stay connected as long as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Co-op experience in Demon's Souls is a bit limited. First of all you can play with a friend only for a single level, and only in levels where you have not defeated the Boss Demon yet. Whether you complete the boss fight or die in the other players world you will always be transferred back to your world.

A player can be summoned in another player world using a Blue Eye Stone. You can find a more detailed description here, on [Demon's Souls wiki](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/online).

Comment: The PC release is for Dark Souls, not Demon's Souls.

Comment: Also, both players' Soul Levels must be within a certain range of each other. (See the Demon's Souls wiki link above.) If both characters stay within 10 levels of each other, it should be fine.